# How do I call a variable from one class to another?

Tags: python, sql, database, tkinter

Im trying to display the variable that was in my login class to my menu class but whenever I do so I always get the error Object login has no attribute user.

Here is my `login.py` file

```
 def login(self):
        global con
        user = self.txt_user.get().strip()
        pwd = self.txt_pass.get().strip()
        if user == "" or pwd == "":
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please fill up all fields!")
        else:
            try :
                con=pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="employee")
                cur=con.cursor()
                cur.execute("select 1 from employeelist where username=%s and password=%s", (user,pwd))
                if cur.rowcount == 1:
                    messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Login Successful", parent=self.root)
                    self.menu()
                else:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Wrong Username or Password. Please try again!")
            except Exception as ex:
                messagebox.showerror("Error",f"Error due to: {str(ex)}",parent=self.root)
            finally:
                con.close()


    def menu(self):
        self.root.destroy()
        menu.MenuForm()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    obj = Login(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Here is my `menu.py` file

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
import login

class Menu:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Main Menu")
        self.root.geometry("1350x768+0+0")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Images/bgimage.jpg")
        bg = Label(self.root, image=self.bg).place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        framemenu = Frame(self.root, bg="white")

        framemenu.place(x=350, y=100, height=500, width=700)
        welcometitle = Label(framemenu, text="Welcome " + login.Login.user(), font=("Arial", 30, "bold"), fg="orange", bg="white").place(x=70,y=70)



def MenuForm():
    win = Tk()
    obj = Menu(win)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    obj = Menu(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I have imported `login` in my `menu` class but it still gives me the error object has no instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow @Hosseinreza's approach to improve your code but if you want to work with your existing code then pass the user attribute to the menu class like below code excerpts

```
def login(self)
   if cur.rowcount == 1:
       messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Login Successful", parent=self.root)
       self.menu(user)

def menu(self, user):
        self.root.destroy()
        menu.MenuForm(user)
```

then in Menu class, you can use it as below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image

class Menu:
    def __init__(self,root, user):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Main Menu")
        self.root.geometry("1350x768+0+0")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Images/bgimage.jpg")
        bg = Label(self.root, image=self.bg).place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        framemenu = Frame(self.root, bg="white")

        framemenu.place(x=350, y=100, height=500, width=700)
        welcometitle = Label(framemenu, text="Welcome " + user, font=("Arial", 30, "bold"), fg="orange", bg="white").place(x=70,y=70)



def MenuForm(user):
    win = Tk()
    obj = Menu(win, user)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    obj = Menu(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Better pass the user to `menu.MenuForm()` via argument instead:

```py
class Login:
    ...

    def login(self):
        user = self.txt_user.get().strip()
        pwd = self.txt_pass.get().strip()
        if user == "" or pwd == "":
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please fill up all fields!")
        else:
            try :
                con=pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="employee")
                cur=con.cursor()
                cur.execute("select 1 from employeelist where username=%s and password=%s", (user,pwd))
                if cur.rowcount == 1:
                    messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Login Successful", parent=self.root)
                    self.menu(user) # pass user to self.menu()
                else:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Wrong Username or Password. Please try again!")
            except Exception as ex:
                messagebox.showerror("Error",f"Error due to: {str(ex)}",parent=self.root)
            finally:
                con.close()

    def menu(self, user):
        self.root.destroy()
        menu.MenuForm(user) # pass user to menu.MenuForm()
```

---

`menu.py`:

```py
from tkinter import *
#from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Menu:
    def __init__(self, root, user): # user passed as argument
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Main Menu")
        self.root.geometry("1350x768+0+0")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Images/bgimage.jpg")
        bg = Label(self.root, image=self.bg).place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        framemenu = Frame(self.root, bg="white")

        framemenu.place(x=350, y=100, height=500, width=700)
        welcometitle = Label(framemenu, text="Welcome " + user, font=("Arial", 30, "bold"), fg="orange", bg="white").place(x=70,y=70)

def MenuForm(user): # user passed as argument
    win = Tk()
    obj = Menu(win, user) # pass user to `Menu` class

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    obj = Menu(root, "user")
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Importing is not enough.
When you are working with `objects` , if you wanna use an `object` first of all you have to make an instance then you can work with the instance , here's an example:

```
class login():
        def __init__(self):
                print("Hi im Login Object")

class main():
        def __init__(self):
                login_obj = login() # Instance created

main()
```

As you see I made an instance of class `Login` into `main` class then it Worked.

Output:

```
Hi im Login Object
```